# How to save static data or variable when Device is Switched On from off state

Tags: android

I use some static variable in my project , the stored data in the static variable get vanish when I Switch On my mobile from OFF state or vicevarsa.

I want to restore my static variable/data same as previous.How can I do that.

Thank you.

Comment: use Preferences Or Sqlite DaTabase it is better solution

Comment: The lifetime of a static variable tends to be the lifetime of the class, which means the class dies as soon as your *mobile* is switched off.  A program runs on RAM, a temporary memory.  Store your variables in some sort of permanent storage, like a file or database.

Comment: If you find a answer helpful and that solves your question, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save it in shared prefrences. And then when you switch it on, it will still be there!

Comment: oh..h..h ok. Thank you Vera.